# Magento2 : How to add row/pattern type of customer attribute

Tags: magento2, attributes, magento2.3, customer-attribute, dynamic-rows

How to add a `row/pattern` type of custom `customer attribute` (dynamic rows). We have the below attribute in Magento 1, we need to achieve the same in Magento 2.

[image]

I don't find any code reference for this, If anything I found, I'll update here.

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: The answer for this can be found here https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/225617/how-to-create-a-dynamic-generated-admin-fields

Comment: @ArshadM Thanks! You are mentioned answer was related to the system configurations field rendering not for customer attribute.